# Distinguishing a user from a bot. preventing clickjacking

Tags: click, bots

How can I prevent clickjacking, which basically means preventing users from maliciously clicking on my ads, etc.

What sort of parameters apart from using their ip address can I use to judge if a user has clicked with interest in the ad?

Comment: I wouldn't be trying to stop people from clicking on *my* ad's ;)

Comment: @Blender, I think he's talking about ads he placed, not ads on his page.  It's not really clear though.

Comment: Blender: You would if you had to pay for every ad that was clicked on, and that person 'clicked' using a server farm of bots.

Answer (score 0):

Once they get to your page use JavaScript to detect mouse movement.  If there is none then it's likely to be a bot.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener("load", 
    function() 
    {
        document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", 
            function() 
            { 
                alert("Welcome real user.") 
            },
            false);
    },
    false);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not 100% because screen readers won't have mouse movement and some people navigate the web with a keyboard, but that's extremely rare.